Table with fixed headers top and left and overflow
I want to create this layout using CSS (Tailwind would be great):

I have this CSS and HTML but when adding more columns and using width: 100% and for fixed_header and tr, it wraps the months entries instead of using overflow:


.fixed_header {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.td,
.th {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index:1;
}

.th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tr {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 500px;
}

.thead>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  
}

div.tbody>div.tr>div:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  
}
<div class="fixed_header">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Col 1</div>
      <div class="th">Col 2</div>
      <div class="th">Col 3</div>
      <div class="th">Col 4</div>
      <div class="th">Col 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 1-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 2-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 3-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 4-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 5-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 6-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 7-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 1-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 2-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 3-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 4-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 5-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 6-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 7-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 1-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 1-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 2-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 2-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 3-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 3-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 4-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 4-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 5-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 5-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 6-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 6-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">row 7-0</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-1</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-2</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-3</div>
      <div class="td">row 7-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onjvash4/
JSFiddle with described changes: https://jsfiddle.net/onjvash4/1/
Result:

Updated JSFiddle that almost works: https://jsfiddle.net/onjvash4/2/
Remaining issue: background-color: inherit makes the first column transparent. Setting another background-color breaks the sticky behavior

